# Is there a relationship between HDL-C and LDL-C?

Tags: biochemistry, metabolism, fat-metabolism, cholesterol

*For a gentle introduction to cholesterol and its functions, see a [great answer](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/5154/4016) on SE Biology*

Whenever I read about how to deal with cholesterol level, the [rule](https://www.health.harvard.edu/blog/the-new-cholesterol-guidelines-what-you-need-to-know-2018112615422) is to keep a low LDL fraction, ad a high HDL one.

How to achieve this usually falls into the categories of a healthy body (sport), a healthy diet and possibly medicamentation.

Since generally the advice is more or less the same for both goals (lowering one fraction and increasing the other one), **I was wondering if there is a strong relationship between these fractions.** In other words - is moving one in the right directions automatically drags the other one (also in the right direction)?

Anecdotally (and this is what triggered my question), I saw my LDL crash almost by 250% (not by chance but through a good diet, etc. - over a few months) and, surprisingly, the HDL go down by 30% as well.